# Выполнение команды при запуске контейнера Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Что то совсем запустался. Нужно почистить кеш laravel пр запуске контейнера. Но проблема в том, что скрипт чистки кеша завершается и вместе с ним завершает работу контейнер. Пытался лепить костыли типа:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/php", "/var/www/laravel/artisan", "cache:clear"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
===========
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "'php /var/www/laravel/artisan cache:clear'", "&&", "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
==========
CMD ["/var/www/laravel/artisan", "cache:clear", "&&", "/bin/bash"]
```

И еще миллион комбинаций, но ничего не помогает. В лучшем случае он удаляет слой с этой командой:

```
Step 11/12 : CMD /usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel/artisan cache:clear
---> Running in 4c1202595b35
---> 5dff8f60522c
Removing intermediate container 4c1202595b35
```

Удаляет то почему? что я делаю не так? Помогите плиз разобраться

PS
Изначально проблема в том, что метод withoutOverlapping() крон задачи защищающий задачу очереди от наложения сохраняется в кеш на сутки и при перезагрузке/пересоздании контейнера не запускает крон-задач т.к. читает в кеше что она уже запущена. Может есть другие способы решения проблемы?

Comment: вы не правильно используете docker - поэтому и проблемы. контейнер должен быть неизменный (immutable). то есть его можно пересоздать с нуля и это не повлияет на систему, так изменяемы данные должны быть на отдельном разделе (volume).

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Вы хотите предложить поселить демона и каждый крон-таск в отдельном контейнере? Не будет ли это излишним расточительством ресурсов?

Comment: нет. я этого не предлагаю. я предлагаю разделить данные и  сервера

Comment: @MikhailVaysman можно чуть подробнее что вы имеете ввиду? данные хранятся отдельно, конфиг контейнера никто не трогает. мне нужен скорее триггер для очистки кеша при перезапуске контейнера ибо он убивает живущего внутри демона, а новый по крону не запускается из-за кеширования (защита от наложения). У вас есть какие то конкретные предложения, которые могли бы помочь решить проблему по фен-шую?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос ваш Dockerfile целиком и команду который вы запускаете контейнер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CMD /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/php /var/www/laravel/artisan cache:clear' && /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

Такой костыль помог. Удаление слоя видимо нормально. т.к. никаких изменений не произошло (только файлы проекта изменились, которые не являются частью образа) докер грохнул слой.